# Processing/ Voronoi Diagram 3D - Simple Box

Tags: java, 3d, processing, voronoi

I searched a bunch of websites to find a working example of how to create a Voronoi based 3D Box. 
The following link shows you guys for what i am looking for. Can someone help me out with this?

I created "Seedpoints" in a 3D Box and now what? ... couldn´t find a good and simple example on openprocessing either.

Thank you in advance.

[Picture](http://api.ning.com/files/sKB0yTzFDNWfvECA%2aJ%2aTSuZlfgpVElpuZaendQ2dkuwERb%2aUmV6F3yoVaktdX%2aBVZONRNBuxL0oWD1H62G74OsxkkTXDbKCZ/voronoi_box.jpg)

Comment: do you want a solid shape with a voronoi-based texture on the surface, or are you looking for a full 3D voronoi tessellation?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Voro++](http://math.lbl.gov/voro++/) is doing exactly what you want. However, it is written in C++ but creating a small wrapper using [swig](http://www.swig.org) for example will provide you a java binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with 2D texture created by processing library [Mesh](http://leebyron.com/else/mesh/) (just use `getEdges()` function to draw border lines of regions)  and use it with texture mapping on your 3D box.

Answer (score 0):

Voronoi diagrams can be easily handled with pixel shaders depending on the format of your seed points [This example](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldl3W8) is the best I've found so far but it relies upon points whose coordinates are computed inside the shader, at least to my understanding.